# ML compilation code error

Tags: ml

I can't understand the error.

I run this and I get the error:

```
7.18-7.22 Error: argument of raise is not an exception [tycon mismatch]

  raised: ?.R1

  in expression:

    raise (E y)
val it = () : unit
```

**This is the code:**

```
exception E of real;

fun g (y)= raise E(y);

fun f(z)=

 let

 datatype R1=E of int;

 fun x(y)= raise E(y);

 in

 z(3);

 x(3)

 end;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second use of `raise`, the `E` refers to the constructor `E` of the datatype `R1`, which isn't an exception. Its local definition shadows the outer definition of the exception `E`. Rename one or the other to resolve this error.